# How to perform one operation at time android?

Tags: java, android

I am making android calculator. I made some functions but the first problem is double clickable operation.I tried but couldn't. when i click two operations consequently both are appearing on the text view. i'll post my code if you can solve double clickable operation problem please post your code on comment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView _screen;
    private TextView _result;
    private String display = "";
    private String currentOperator;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
        _result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_result);
    }

    public void updateScreen() {
        _screen.setText(display);
    }

    public void onClickNumber(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        display += b.getText();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void onClickOperator(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        display += b.getText();
        currentOperator = b.getText().toString();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void clear() {
        display = "";
        currentOperator = "";
    }

    public void onClickClear(View view) {
        clear();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public double operate(String a, String op, String b) {
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);
            case "-":
                return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);
            case "*":
                return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);
            case "/":
                return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public void onClickEqual(View v) {
        String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));
        _result.setText(String.valueOf(operate(operation[0], currentOperator,  operation[1])));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your question regarding double operation is that Let suppose you are performing operation of + and when you click again for + it gets displayed 2 times on textview (as your method updateScreen suggest). If that is the problem, you can do as mentioned below

```
 public void updateScreen() {
        if (screen.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            screen.setText(display);
        } else if (!display.equalsIgnoreCase(screen.getText().toString())) {
            screen.setText("");
            screen.setText(display);
        } else {
            //this is the case that means that operator is already set on the text
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: The problem is not like this. When i click + and - both(  + -  ) are on text view. When i pressed two operation consequently  only one must appear.

Comment: did you try above solution?